# How does one find the moment of inertia about a line passing through the centroid of a cone?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[Image 1 detailing the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux4Qw.jpg)

[Image 2 showing the part of the working I do not understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlBwe.jpg)

In image 2 part d, I'm unsure why the moment of inertia with respect to the y axis, Iy, is equal to Ic plus the expression shown. Could someone explain to me the intuition behind this equation? Can this be extended to lines other than that passing through the centroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He has applied the *Parallel axis theorem* . MI through CG is minimum and if the displacement is $d$, we have to add on extra

$$\dfrac12 m d^2$$

For a 3d cone the centroid is one-fourth its height from its base. ( compare for a 2d triangle .. it is one-third ). Applied mechanics math, not pure math.